# SQL Server: 2 questions for homework can't figure it out

Tags: sql, sql-server

Both questions will be working off of this table:

```
CREATE TABLE WINE
(
    wineID              INT,
    wineName            VARCHAR(50),
    wineYear            CHAR(4),
    winePrice           DECIMAL(5,2),
    wineDesc            VARCHAR(255),
    wineHarvest         DATE,
    wineAlcohol         DECIMAL(5,2),
    wineSugar_gl            DECIMAL(5,2),   
    wineAcidity_gl          DECIMAL(3,2),
    winePHLevel         DECIMAL(3,2),
    wineIsMaloLactic        BIT,
    wineCaseProduction      SMALLINT,

    CONSTRAINT pk_wine_wineID   PRIMARY KEY(wineID)
);

/*22 New Wine Records*/

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(1,'Dean''s List Chardonnay','2007', 27.95, 'This Chardonnay provides enticing aromas of apricots, vanilla bean and butterscotch. A medium bodied Chardonnay, with a silky mouth texture, and nice acidity for balance. Flavours of caramel, peach and candied lemon dominate the palate', '2007-09-20',13.0, 3.1, 5.6, 3.4, 0, 200);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(2,'Barrel Fermented Chardonnay','2008', 18.95, 'This Chardonnay provides tantalizing aromas of caramel, vanilla bean and peach pie. This full-bodied wine has a silky mouth texture, offering characteristics of butterscotch and baked apples on the palate, leading to a long and lingering finish.', '2008-10-13',13.5, 3, 6, 3.46, 0, 320);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(3,'Unoaked Chardonnay','2009', 14.95, 'With lively aromas of citrus and melon, this refreshing Chardonnay offers flavours of lemon and green apple on the palate', '2009-10-29',13.0, 6, 7, 3.3, 1, 190);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(4,'Gewurztraminer','2009', 14.95, 'This is a highly aromatic Gewurztraminer, offering aromas of lychee, rose petals and citrus fruit. On the palate,this wine has lively acidity, with flavours of grapefruit and orange marmalade', '2009-10-14',12.0, 5, 7.2, 3.2, 1, 293);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(5,'Sauvignon Blanc','2008', 14.95, 'Our 2008 Sauvignon Blanc is highly aromatic providing aromas of citrus and fresh cut grass. This wine is nicely balanced, with refreshing acidity and offers flavours of citrus fruit and green fig on the palate', '2008-09-29',12.0, 4, 6.9, 3.4, 1, 270);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(6,'Riesling ','2008', 13.95, 'Our 2008 Riesling offers aromas of lemon and lime on the nose, followed by flavours of green apple and citrus fruit on the palate. This is a nicely balanced wine offering crisp acidity, and a lovely finish', '2008-10-08',11.5, 9, 6.8, 3.2, 1, 420);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(7,'Riesling Semi-Dry','2009', 13.95, 'Our 2009 Riesling offers aromas of citrus fruit and peach on the nose, followed by flavours of green apple and citrus fruit on the palate. A nicely balanced wine with crisp acidity, and a hint of sweetness', '2009-10-30',12.0, 18, 8.5, 3, 1, 227);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(8,'College White','2008', 10.95, 'A Chardonnay/Vidal blend offering aromas of peach and orange blossoms. This wine is nicely balanced, with mild acidity and offers flavours of tropical fruit on the palate', '2008-09-20',12.0, 5.9, 6.2, 3.3, 1, 250);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(9,'Dean''s List Prodigy Icewine','2009', 37.95, 'This Vidal/Chardonnay/Riesling blend has a very expressive nose, with aromas of candied lemon and tropical fruit. Flavours of mango and honey coat the palate, with a perfect balance between acidity and sweetness', '2010-01-29',11.0, 211, 8.6, 3.4, 1, 96);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(10,'Dean''s List Savant Icewine','2008', 69.95, 'This Icewine offers aromas of strawberry jam, and rhubarb on the nose, with similar flavours on the palate. This wine has a beautiful mouth texture, with a perfect balance between sweetness and acidity', '2009-01-21',12.0, 225, 3.4, 8.8, 1, 61);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(11,'Dean''s List Cabernet Franc Icewine','2009', 29.95, 'This Cabernet Franc Icewine offers aromas of strawberry, honey and rhubarb on the nose, with similar flavours on the palate. This wine has a beautiful mouth texture, with a perfect balance between sweetness and acidity', '2010-01-29',11.0, 210, 8.4, 3.4, 1, 472);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(12,'Dean''s List Meritage','2007', 47.95, 'This complex Meritage offers black currants, plum and cedar on the nose, with flavours of cassis, dark chocolate and blackberry. Full bodied, with firm yet ripe tannins, and a long and lingering finish', '2006-10-01',13.0, 2.8, 6, 3.51, 0, 250);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(13,'Dean''s List Pinot Noir Canadian Oak Project','2007', 38.95, 'This limited edition Pinot offers aromas of ripe strawberries, cigar and mocha. This medium bodied red provides firm, yet ripe tannins and flavours of black cherry and vanilla bean', '2007-10-10',13.0, 3, 5.8, 3.5, 0, 61);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(14,'Meritage ','2005', 37.95, 'This powerhouse Meritage offers jammy black fruit, cassis and eucalyptus on the nose, with similar flavours on the palate. Full-bodied, with firm yet ripe tannins and a beautifully long finish', '2004-10-01',13.0, 2.8, 7.5, 3.51, 0, 275);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(15,'Dean''s List Pinot Noir','2007', 32.95, 'With aromas of beet root, earth and sour cherry, this Pinot offers raspberry and vanilla bean on the palate. A medium bodied Pinot with firm, yet ripe tannins leading to a long finish', '2007-10-10',13.5, 4, 5.8, 3.5, 0, 350);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(16,'Shiraz','2006', 18.95, 'With aromas of cracked black pepper, and red fruit, this Shiraz offers flavours of raspberry, plum and spice. Medium bodied with smooth tannins, and a long and lingering finish', '2005-10-25',13.0, 2.3, 6.6, 3.25, 0, 275);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(17,'Cabernet Franc','2007', 18.95, 'This is a very rich Cabernet Franc with an expressive nose of blackberry jam and crème de cassis. Flavours of black fruit, baking spice and black licorice coat the palate, with a pleasant balance between fruit, tannin, acidity and alcohol. Lovely finish', '2007-10-25',13.0, 4, 6.5, 3.63, 0, 458);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(18,'Pinot Noir','2008', 15.95, 'This Pinot provides aromas of black cherry and earth, followed by flavours of sour cherry and vanilla. Light-medium bodied Pinot with smooth tannins, and a lingering finish', '2008-10-07',13.0, 4.5, 6.2, 3.8, 0, 410);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(19,'Merlot','2006', 15.95, 'With aromas of plum, and black cherries, this Merlot offers firm yet ripe tannins and flavours of black berries and currants. Nice finish', '2006-10-24',13.0, 4.4, 6.5, 3.51, 0, 370);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(20,'Cabernet Sauvignon','2006', 15.95, 'With a nose of black fruits and spice, this Cabernet Sauvignon offers flavours of cassis and anise on the palate', '2006-10-29',13.0, 5, 6.7, 3.5, 0, 270);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(21,'Baco Noir','2006', 11.95, 'Little known in the rest of the world, Baco is a signature hybrid for Ontario. This Baco Noir offers aromas of raisin, vanilla and black cherry, with similar flavours on the palate', '2006-09-01',11.5, 5.5, 9.1, 3.32, 0, 140);

INSERT INTO WINE VALUES(22,'College Red','2008', 10.95, 'This Cabernet Franc/Baco Noir blend offers aromas of jammy fruit, mocha and sweet bell pepper, with similar flavours on the palate. An easy drinking red wine with soft tannins and a pleasant finish', '2008-09-23',12, 3, 7, 3.6, 0, 590);
```

1.How many days has it been since we harvested our 2009 icewines?

```
SELECT wineName
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY, wineHarvest, GETDATE()) AS '# of
 Days Since Harvest'
FROM WINE
WHERE wineName LIKE '%Icewine'
    AND YEAR(wineYear) = '2009';
```

this one my prof told me "Have a look at the data type of the wineYear column, then ask yourself what the YEAR () function is intended for and then give it one more try. You're very close." But I just don't know..

2.What is the name, price, and alcohol percentage of the wine with the highest sugar content/gl?

```
SELECT MAX(wineSugar_gl) AS wineName
    ,winePrice
    ,wineAlcohol
FROM WINE;
```

though for this one I'm getting an error all together and I don't know how to fix it. I need it to show me the name price and alcohol % for the wine with the most sugar.

They're suppose to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. The YEAR function is for parsing the year out of a time, date, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2, or datetimeoffset value.  You actually won't need to use it in your query, since there is already a column to show you what year each wine is.

   `SELECT wineName
       ,DATEDIFF(DAY, wineHarvest, GETDATE()) AS '# of
    Days Since Harvest'
   FROM WINE
   WHERE wineName LIKE '%Icewine'
       AND wineYear = '2009';`
2. You're current query is running an aggregate function (`MAX()`) - something you don't need here.  Aggregate functions are for accumulating values over a number of rows.  However, your value is already sitting in the table!  You could do something like the following:

   `SELECT TOP 1 
       wineSugar_gl
       ,winePrice
       ,wineAlcohol
   FROM WINE
   ORDER BY wineSugar_gl DESC;`

Comment: It does no one any good to do their homework for them.  Give them help and point them in the right direction, sure, but don't outright give them the answer...

Comment: He made attempts, he asked why. Giving the working solution with reasons is not the wrong thing to do.  Giving working solutions with no explanation is a different story.

Comment: I understand what the problem was now, but yes I do agree with Siyual at the same time about that but it's not as though i just sent the question said answer please

Comment: Was your understanding of the issue & SQL itself helped by the answer? That's the helpful question here.

Comment: Yes it was I forgot all about SELECT TOP as for the first question I didn't realize I just had to remove 1 thing.. Feels pretty bad.

Answer (score -2):

1. Since the year column is char(4) you only have to compare it to your string.

   SELECT wineName
       ,DATEDIFF(DAY, wineHarvest, GETDATE()) AS '# of
    Days Since Harvest'
   FROM WINE
   WHERE wineName LIKE '%Icewine'
       AND wineYear = '2009';
2. Here's the second query

   SELECT TOP(1) wineName, winePrice, wineAlcohol FROM wine
   ORDER BY wineSugar_gl DESC